# Получить текущий элемент внутри обработчика события

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input type="text" value="" onkeyup="new Create_table().add_str()" />

function Create_table() {
    this.add_str = function () {
        //как здесь получить доступ к input
    }
}
```

Вот так мне не подходит

```
onkeyup="new Create_table().add_str(this)"
this.add_str=function(self){}
```

Comment: а так: 

    <input type="text" value="" onkeyup="new Create_table(this).add_str()" />

    function Create_table(element) {
        var el = element;
        this.add_str = function () {
            //как здесь получить доступ к input
            el // вот же он
        }
    }

Comment: хехех, почему бы и нет?

Comment: Spectre не помогло,но спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а еще и вот так можно:

```
<input type="text" value="" onkeyup="new Create_table().add_str.call(this)" />

<script>
function Create_table() {
    this.add_str = function () {
        alert(this.value);
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: УРАААААЁ!!!!!!Спасибо.Именно Ваш способ помог.

Comment: ох, неожиданно! :D

Answer (score 0):

Передать внутрь этого самого обработчика текущий DOM-элемент, а именно `this`

Comment: другой способ есть?